# How to use && in JavaScript if statement

Tags: javascript

I want to do is make the dialog popup if one of the inputs are not filled.

My problem is my code works only if all the inputs are empty but if one is filled the dialog wont shows up.

testing link:  http://jsfiddle.net/6wKPr/10/

```
$('#Save').click(function(){
   if($('#name').val() == '' && $('#age').val() == '' && $('#gender').val() == ''){
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
   }
});
```

Comment: Really? Let's think about the meaning of the word and. If name is empty and age is empty and gender is empty do something. I am wondering why this expression is not fulfilled, if only one of the conditions is fulfilled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have been answered, use OR `||` instead of AND `&&`

You might also want to change the condition for the radiobuttons, as the message doesn't show when you fill both texts but not choose an option.

```
$('#Save').click(function(){
   if($('#name').val() == '' || $('#age').val() == '' ||  $("input[name='gender']:checked").val() == undefined){{
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
   }
});
```

Comment: the radio is not working

Comment: try this 

http://jsfiddle.net/WLb6G/

I forgot one $ before the input

Answer (score 3):

Use **OR** operator `||` instead of **AND** `&&` then:

```
$('#Save').click(function(){
   if($('#name').val() === "" || $('#age').val() === "" || $('#gender').val() === ""){
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
   }
});
```

**AND** operator checks for all conditions to be `true` while **OR** executes if any one of the condition is true.

Comment: its not even working. The dialog only show if all the fields are empty same as my current code.

Comment: you have to debug it then, this condition should work

Comment: just made  a sample fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/85ECm/

Comment: how about the radio button?

Comment: radio button one should be selected by default

Comment: for radio you can write:``if($('#gender:checked').length === 0)``

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/85ECm/2/

Answer (score 2):

Use `||` instead of `&&`, which is the equivalent of 'OR'

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `||` (OR) operator:

```
$('#Save').click(function(){
    if($('#name').val() == '' || $('#age').val() == '' || !$('#gender').is(':checked')){
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
   }
});
```

In addition, since you're checking whether either radio button is checked, you can use the [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) functionality of jQuery. This returns a simple `true` or `false` boolean value for easy comparison inside the `if(...)` statement. This makes the `if` statement cleaner and prevents you from having to compare it against the `undefined` value.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/6wKPr/36/)**